# Power BI Embedded Approach for 100s of SQL Targets

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to find the best approach to delivering a BI solution to 400+ customers which each have their own database.

I've got PowerBI Embedded working using service principal licensing and I have the PowerBI service connected to my data through the On Premise Data Gateway.

I've build my first report pointing to 1 of the customer databases.  Which works lovely.

What I want to do next, when embedding the report, is to tell PowerBI, for this session, to get the database from a different database.

I'm struggling to find somewhere where this is explained, or to understand if this is even possible.

I'm trying to avoid creating 400+ WorkSpaces or 400+ Data Sets.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Provided the schemas are the same, you can change the database for your source dataset by using parameters.  This would mean that you would need to use DirectQuery instead of importing the data into the report.  Is that reasonable for your scenario?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Thanks for your reply.  I am using DirectQuery, with caching disabled.  I'm looking at parameters, I'm aware I can change a dataset parameter value, but not in the context of a session, only a workspace, so I have concerns with concurrency.  If I have a user at customer ABC, and a user at customer DEF both load it at the same time.  What data will they see?

Comment: Let me add a reply with a couple of links.  The app would apply the correct database parameter, so each user would only see their own data.

Comment: The bit I was missing was the lack of functionality in the PowerBI interface in Azure. When I switched to PowerBI desktop and then published to Azure. All the tutorials started to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the report to use parameters and these parameters can be used to configure the source for your dataset:
https://www.phdata.io/blog/how-to-parameterize-data-sources-power-bi/

These parameters can be set by the app hosting the embedded report:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters-in-group

Because the app is setting the parameter, each user will only see their own data.  Since this will be a live connection, you would need to think about how the underlying server can support the workload.

An alternative solution would be to consolidate the customer databases into a single database (just the relevant tables) and use row level security to restrict access for each customer.  The advantage to this design is that you take the burden off of the underlying SQL instance and push it into a PBI dataset that is made to handle huge datasets with sub-second response times.
More on that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls

Comment: The bit I was missing was the lack of functionality in the PowerBI interface in Azure.  When I switched to PowerBI desktop and then published to Azure.  All the tutorials started to make sense.